# gitlab remote mirror repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I have set up two gitlab servers, a main server and a server to mirror all my projects repositories.
I am looking for a command line tool/method to configure the "Remote mirror repository" settings of each project, is this possible and how?

Thank you for all your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured everything manually.

Answer (score 0):

### Repository Mirroring

There is support for Repository Mirroring with some versions of Gitlab.
You can enable it through the repository's settings or when importing a repository.
`Settings` > `Pull from a remote repository` > `Mirror repository`

Here are the docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html

---

### Gitlab CI

If that's not available to you, you could probably set up the Gitlab CI to do it.
Create a `gitlab-ci.yml` file in the root of a repository that might look something like this:

```
mirror:
  script: 
  - git clone http://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.mycompany.home/developers/master_project.git &> /dev/null
  - git config --global user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
  - git config --global user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
  - git add --all
  - git commit -m "Push to mirrored repo"
  - git push http://${YOUR_USERNAME}:${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}@gitlab.mycompany.home/developers/mirrored_project.git HEAD:master
```

You can set the variables in `Settings` > `CI / CD` > `Variables`

I haven't tested this, it's just to guide you in a possible direction.

Here are the docs for CI: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#jobs

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks for your response and time to help. What I want to do is push towards the mirror server. The setting can be found at: 

[group] > [project] > Repository > "Push to a remote repository"

I want to automise this, since I can not do this manually over too many projects, it will take too much time, which I don't have. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Since GitLab 12.9 (march 2020) you can configure a "remote mirror" using GitLab API; see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/remote_mirrors.html#create-a-remote-mirror

```
curl --request POST --data "url=https://username:token@example.com/gitlab/example.git" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/42/remote_mirrors"
```